# Going into a directory linked by a link

Tags: shell, symlink, cd-command

When I `cd` a link, my current path is prefixed with the link's path, rather than the path of the directory the link links to. 
E.g.

```
~/dirlinks/maths$ ls -l logic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tim tim 71 Jul 27 10:24 logic -> /windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/logic

~/dirlinks/maths$ cd logic
~/dirlinks/maths/logic$ pwd
/home/tim/dirlinks/maths/logic

~/dirlinks/maths/logic$ cd ..
~/dirlinks/maths$
```

I would like to have my current path changed to the path of the linked dir, so that I can work with the parent dirs of the linked dir as well. Besides `ls` the link to find out the linked dir, and then `cd` into it, what are some simpler ways to accomplish that? For example, after `cd` into a link, how do you change your current path to the path of the linked dir?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With POSIX shell, you can use `-P` option of [cd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) builtin:

```
cd -P <link>
```

With `bash`, from `man bash`:

> The -P option  says  to use the physical directory structure instead
>   of following symbolic links (see also the  -P  option  to  the  set
>   builtin command)

Comment: You can do this `cd -P .` after the original `cd`.

Answer (score 7):

Korn-like shells keep track of symbolic links in the path to the current directory (this is known as logical current directory tracking). If you want to expand all symbolic links, pass the option `-P` to the `cd` builtin (for physical current directory tracking):

```
cd -P logic
```

If you're in a directory which you've accessed via a symbolic link and want to switch the tracked current directory to the path with symbolic links expanded, run

```
cd -P .
```

If you want to print the path to the current directory with symbolic links expanded, run `pwd -P`. In bash, if you want to turn off logical tracking, run `set -P`; in zsh, run `set -w` or `setopt chase_links`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `readlink` to determine where your link points, and provide this output as the target of your `cd`.

```bash
cd "$(readlink <link>)"
```

In the case of additional symlinks pointing to symlinks, `readlink` will simply provide the target, unless you specify one of it's options to follow symlinks to a canonical file target, for example `readlink -f <link>`.

> [readlink](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/0/readlink/) - print value of a symbolic link or canonical file name
>
> -f, --canonicalize
>   canonicalize  by  following  every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist
>
> -e, --canonicalize-existing
>   canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively, all components must exist
>
> -m, --canonicalize-missing
>   canonicalize  by  following  every symlink in every component of the given name recursively, without requirements on components existence