# Symlinked directories and output redirect

Tags: bash, io-redirection, symlink, cd-command

When I run the following command, where `symlinked-dir` is just that - a symlink to another directory, `cat` complains that there is no such file. There is, indeed, no such file - it's created in the parent directory of the *real* path instead, *but* it contains the the path through the symlink outputted by `pwd`, so at least `cd` and `pwd` know where they are, link-wise. I want the redirect to know it too.

`cd symlinked-dir && echo $(pwd) >> ../tmp && cd .. && cat tmp`

So, what modifications should I make to get the above command work?

Edit: the shell is Bash on either Debian or Gentoo (both work the same way).

Comment: What shell on what Unix are you using here?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's Bash. Tested on Debian and Gentoo, both reasonably modern, but not newest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding directory symlinks traversals and the parent directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180620/understanding-directory-symlinks-traversals-and-the-parent-directory)

Comment: @muru Not exactly a duplicate, as there is only explanation, but no solution in there. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284662/how-do-you-normalize-a-file-path-in-bash) question turns out more relevant.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146843/going-into-a-directory-linked-by-a-link might be closer then.

Comment: @muru nope. I want to stay on the symlinked path and `realpath -s` does just that, as opposed to just `realpath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
(cd symlinked-dir && pwd) >> tmp && cat tmp
```

Where we run the `cd` in a subshell so it only affect that subshell and perform the redirection outside the subshell (and before the subshell is even created).

Replace `pwd` with `pwd -P` if you want the canonical (symlink-free) absolute path of the `symlinked-dir`. Though if you have a `realpath` command, then you can do it simply with `realpath symlinked-dir > tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, reading `..` of the directory will not help us, so we must solve this at the symbolic path level. One of the ways to do so is listed below:

`cd symlinked-dir && echo $(pwd) >> $(realpath -s $(pwd)/../tmp) && cd .. && cat tmp`